# CentOS 7.8 installation on HP Envy x360 laptop aborts on partition definition

Tags: laptop, installation, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7

I'm trying to install CentOS 7 on HP Envy x360 laptop.
However, as soon as the 'Done' is clicked in the 'Partition Definition' stage, the installation is aborted with the following messages.
[image: Unknown Error]
[image: Unknown Error - debug]

### How to recreate:

- Complete the Windows 10 installation
- Create an installation USB containing RHEL 7.8 DVD ISO image
- Boot the HP Envy x360 laptop and press F10 to get to the boot menu
- Set the USB to be the first boot device
- Insert the RHEL 7.8 Installation USB into a USB port on the HP laptop
- Power off/on the laptop
- Choose English as language and click on 'Done'
- Choose 'Define Partitions' and click 'Done'

at this stage the installation bombs.

Note:
The exact same behaviour occurs when trying to install RHEL 7.6/7.8 and CentOS 7.6

Edit 1:
`fdisk` output
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_8Lglkd_3-rJ5BXI_pkvHvfKaVl-WGW9/view?usp=sharing

**Solution:**
Seems the CentOS got confused with the NTFS partition on which Windows 10 is installed.
When I told the CentOS installation to clobber the unknown (i.e. NTFS) partition, the installation went ahead without a hitch.

Comment: I faced something like this while installing fedora 27 ; Bug - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1393381 ; I don't think booting in safe graphics mode will be helpful but give it a try or use CentOS 8

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Seems the CentOS got confused with the NTFS partition on which Windows 10 is installed.
When I told the CentOS installation to clobber the unknown (i.e. NTFS) partition, the installation went ahead without a hitch.